# Why can't I return the last value of the recursive fuction in C?

Tags: c, function, recursion

I've been trying to build a recursive function which calculates the max value, but even I can see the total value when I print in the function, I can't return the value to the main function. Can you tell me where do I do wrong? Thanks for help!

note : more explanation about what I ve been trying to build is : user defines an object and as long as user doesn't give the price, I keep asking what the object is..

small example :

```
Define the object:  
Car  
What is Car?:  
4*Wheel+1*Frame  
What is Wheel?:  
2*Rim  
What is Rim?  
5.0  
What is Frame?:  
10.0  
Total is : 50.0
```

Current code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define INPUT_SIZE 101

void delete_space(char arr[])
{
    int a, i, j, len;
    for(a = 0; a < INPUT_SIZE; a++)
    {
        for(i = 0; i < INPUT_SIZE; i++)
        {
            if(arr[i] == ' ')
            {
                for(j = i; j < INPUT_SIZE; j++)
                {
                    arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


double result(char input[], double coeff, double total)
{
    /* if the input is number, num_of_obj is 0, if the input is object, num_or_obj is more than 0.
     */
    int i, k = 1, num_of_obj = 0;
    char temp_input[INPUT_SIZE];
    char temp_input_1[INPUT_SIZE];
    char x;
    int* p;
    double value;
    p = (int*)calloc(1, sizeof(int));
    p[0] = 0;
    printf("What is %s:?\n", input);
    scanf("%[^\n]s", temp_input);
    getchar();
    delete_space(temp_input);
    for(i = 0; i < INPUT_SIZE; i++)
    {
        if(temp_input[i] == '*')
        {
            num_of_obj++;
        }
    }
    if(num_of_obj == 0) // if the input is number.
    {
        sscanf(temp_input, "%lf", &value);
        total = total + coeff * value;
        printf("total : %lf", total);
        return total;
    }
    if(num_of_obj > 0)
    {
        for(i = 0; i < INPUT_SIZE; i++)
        {
            if(temp_input[i] == '+')
            {
                p = (int*)realloc(p, (k + 1) * sizeof(int));
                p[k] = i + 1;
                k++;
            }
        }
        for(i = 0; i < k; i++)
        {
            sscanf(&temp_input[p[i]], "%lf%c%[^+]s", &coeff, &x, temp_input_1);
            result(temp_input_1, coeff, total);
        }
    }
    printf("test");
    return total;
}

int main()
{
    double total = 0;
    char input[INPUT_SIZE];
    printf("Define the object :\n");
    scanf("%[^\n]s", input);
    getchar();
    delete_space(input);
    printf("total : %.2lf", result(input, 0, 0));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: To be honest, I'm not quite sure what your program is doing. But it looks like you are not using the return value of your recursive result() call.
Try `total =  result(temp_input_1, coeff, total);`

Comment: i ve put a small example to make it clear what my goal is. And I ve already tried your suggestion but still the same..

Comment: Look like you want to create an expression tree to parse the input

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the main issue is the recursive call: `result(temp_input_1, coeff, total);`, which is ignoring the returned result.

Two possible solutions: (1) do the aggregation in `result` OR (2) tail recursion. I'm not sure that this case fit into tail recursion (or that there are any benefits here). Consider removing the 'total' from `result` prototype, and doing the aggregation (over the 'components') in the loop.

```
double result(char input[], double coeff) {
   double total ;

   ...
        for(i = 0; i < k; i++)
        {
            sscanf(&temp_input[p[i]], "%lf%c%[^+]s", &coeff, &x, temp_input_1);
            total += result(temp_input_1, coeff, total);
        }
```

Side comment: Consider also removing the 'delete_space' function. I believe it does not property `fix` the string. Much easier to skip over the spaces in the `scanf` call.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stackoverflow! I too am new here, but if you word your questions right, you'll get better answers. If this is a homework assignment, I highly recommend including that, it can be hard to follow descriptions.

So as a general rule of thumb, when writing C functions its best to use as few return statements as possible. But I too have difficulty with this.

It looks like your are checking for

1. is first condition met?
2. **if not** check next condition

should you be using if, if else, and else?

Also you have if statements with no else, generally needed, especially in a recursive function (you might be skipping over the next step after the last recursive call)

Hope this helps! Swamped with the end of the semester myself or else I would have attempted a solution!

Answer (score 0):

You need three things to write a recursive method successfully:

1. A terminating condition, so that the method doesn't call itself forever,
2. Some work to do, and
3. A recursive call.

Consider the following code:

```
typedef struct node{
  void* item;
  struct node* next;
} Node;

int CountNodes(Node* list)
{
    if (list == null) return 0;
    return 1 + CountNodes(list.next);
}
```

This code works because it counts the current node plus all remaining nodes.  The recursive call counts the next node and all remaining nodes.  And so on.